# "Type 'task.Type' has no subscript members" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

This code gives me an error; Type 'task.Type' has no subscript members

This is my code:

```
struct task {
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var desc = "Un-Described"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = task[]()

    func addTask(name: String, desc: String){
        tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))        
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `[task]()`

Comment: It's actually special syntax for `Array<task>()`. It would also help to name classes/structs with capital letters, e.g. `Task` instead of `task`, to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square brackets should be around the structure name. Like so `[task]()`, the same as you do `[String]`

Having an object inside the square brackets means: *create an array of this type*.

The `()` means: *create a new instance (like a copy) of this object*. So the struct works like a template. For example if you needed two tasks:

```
let myTask = task()
let sistersTask = task()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create an array of tasks, it should be:

```
var tasks = [task]()
```

You have your type outside of the array.